# /login page in Craft keeps redirecting to home page. What could be causing that?

Tags: redirect, login

I have a structured channel setup to house all the static pages on the site. All of the pages display fine on the page entry template. But the `/login` page does not. It displays fine in Live Preview. But on the actual site it immediately redirects to the homepage.

Is `/login` a protected keyword or something?

My .htaccess file is quite normal

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And I have the Sprout SEO plugin handling some basic redirects. I'm at a loss to know where to even look next.  Any ideas?

This isn't a login form to get into Craft by the way. It's to login to a separate website entirely.

Comment: If you give the entry a different slug than `'login'` (something random, e.g. `'foobar'`) does it still redirect?

Comment: No. If I change it, it works correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/login is the default login page for Craft (see https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings and scroll down to the users section ). You can override it by adding something like this to your config file:

'loginPath' => 'members/login',